# How do I enable the intl extension in CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp-3.0, php-7, php-extension, mamp-pro, intl

I am using CakePHP 3 and MAMP Pro server for my project. When I am trying to bake the cake, this error shows up:

> Fatal error: You must enable the intl extension to use CakePHP.

I have even included **intl.so** and **extension=php_intl.dll** in my php.ini file but couldn't figure out solution for this error.

Comment: Have you tried restarting apache?

Comment: Yes. I have tried restarting Mamp after making the changes.

Answer (score 6):

this issue was happening to me some  days ago. I had installed Ubuntu 18.04 and php 7.1.

I was trying to run the comman `php cake.php bake` in orden to use cakephp's console but I was getting the following error message:

- `You must enable the intl extension to use CakePHP.`

This extension (`intl`) was installed for php 7.1 (`php7.1-intl`) but this message was appearing every time I used `php cake.php bake`

After some google searches, I saw that I have to install the extension but with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install php-intl
```

The same issue happened with `mbstring` extension, I used the command:

```
sudo apt-get install php-mbstring
```

then I restarted the apache server with:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 3):

It's difficult to pinpoint exactly what's wrong without seeing your system setup. However based on what was said in the question, you may be setting up the intl extension incorrectly.

First off, if your OS is Linux/macOS and the PHP extension is a shared library (i.e. has a `.so` extension) then the `php.ini` entry should be `extension=intl.so` *not* `extension=php_intl.dll`. Also make sure the `intl.so` file is in the directory configured under the ini entry `extension_dir`. Otherwise make sure the extension ini entry is fully qualified (e.g. `extension=/path/to/extension/dir/intl.so`).

If you are using a Linux OS that has a package manager such as Debian/Ubuntu, you may be able to more easily install the extension for the PHP packaged for that distro. For example, in Ubuntu/Debian the package `php5-intl` provides the intl extension for PHP5 (I assume it's something similar for PHP7 if you've enabled those repos).

If you build PHP from source, you can try bundling the extension into your PHP. See the instructions from the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/intl.installation.php).

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue.

I added `extension="php_intl.dll"` in php.ini and restarted the Apache server.

Now it is working.

Comment: Note this wil only work for windows users.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. After starting from scratch, I did :

```
$ brew install php
$ composer install && composer update && composer dump-autoload --optimize
$ composer self-update && composer create-project --prefer-dist cakephp/app:^3.8 cms
$ cd cms
$ bin/cake server
```

And it was working !